# Error al sumar cantidades de un arreglo PHP

Tags: php

tengo un problema en PHP. Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
               $MontoTotal = 0;
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($Montos); $i++)
                {
                    $MontoTotal .= $Montos[$i];
                }
                print_r($MontoTotal);
```

Montos es un arreglo con dos cantidades, y quiero irlas sumando y guardarlo en la variable $MontoTotal,
pero al pimprimir $MontoTotal las cantidades se concatenan y no se suman, entiendo que porque son string, pero por ejemplo hago la suma manual de esta manera:

```
$MontoTotal = $Montos[0] + $Montos[1];
```

si me asigna el valor de la suma a la variable $MontoTotal, por qué razón en el ciclo  se concatenan y si lo hago de esta otra manera si se suman correctamente?
Necesito hacerlo dentro de un ciclo ya que puede que sea mas de dos numeros los que se sumen por lo que no puede ser siempre manualmente con los indices 0 y 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En PHP, `.` se usa para concatenar cadenas. `+` para sumar cantidades numéricas.

```
$MontoTotal = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Montos); $i++)
{
    $MontoTotal += $Montos[$i];
}
print_r($MontoTotal);
```

Eso debería funcionar

Comment: Tienes razón, me confundí con esa parte, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si es para sumar valores numéricos de un array también puedes hacerlo con [`array_sum()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php), una función de PHP que sirve para calcular la suma de los valores de un array.

La sintaxis en simple:

```
$laSuma=array_sum($elArray);
```

Algunos ejemplos:

```
$elArray=array(1,2);
$laSuma=array_sum($elArray); #Daría 3

$elArray=array(1,2,3,4,5);
$laSuma=array_sum($elArray); #Daría 15


$elArray=array(1,2,3,4,-5);
$laSuma=array_sum($elArray); #Daría 5
```